# Longitud del error devuelto por un web Service

Tags: .net, webservice

Al consumir un servicio Web recibo este error:

- Los primeros 1024 bytes de la respuesta fueron....

Esos 1024 caracteres son parte de una página html que está devolviendo el servidor. Abarca la parte del `<head>` y el comienzo del `<body>` pero no llega al final del todo (debería terminar en `</html>`)

El servidor tiene que estar devolviendo una respuesta más extensa (la página web entera) con lo que si sólo recibo 1024 caracteres, el código que captura la respuesta para ver el erro se está truncando.

¿Se puede aumentar dicho tamaño?

Comment: Te recomiendo que agregues más información, (rest o soap), que tipo de dato usas, código. La pregunta está muy incompleta.

Answer (score 1):

no sé si se trata de un servicio WCF o no. Ni que versión de framework estás utilizando, pero aquí paso algunas posibles soluciones a tu problema:

1. **Panel de Control** > **Opciones de internet** > **Conexiones** > **Configuración LAN** > **Avanzado** > **Configuración Proxy**. Si utilizas proxy, puedes colocar tu dirección IP como una excepción. Si no utilizas debes marcar la opción "Detectar configuración automáticamente".
2. En tu archivo **web.config** del servicio modifica tu xml de la siguiente manera:

   <system.web>
       ...
       <sessionState cookieless="UseCookies" />
       <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" enableVersionHeader="false" executionTimeout="1200" shutdownTimeout="1200" maxRequestLength="103424" />
   </system.web>

Answer (score 0):

Edita el archivo de configuración httpd.conf
y agrega esta línea:

```
LimitRequestLine 99999
```

Y reinicia el servidor Apache, si es que este es el caso

A mí me funcionó cuando un web service no recibía cierto tamaño de valores, porque la configuración por default no transporta gran tamaño de datos

Comment: Ando un poco perdido pero no creo que sea el caso. El web service no es mio. Es de la Agencia Tributaria española. Me piden el error para ayudarme con la solucion pero no veo el mensaje completos.

Comment: Te recomiendo una leida a este concepto:
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#limitrequestline

Answer (score 0):

intentaste con esto ?

```
  <system.web>
            <httpRuntime executionTimeout="500" maxRequestLength="29296" />
          </system.web>
```